# How to write SQL sub-query in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, left-join

Here is sample data I am looking for total buying trade value and total selling trades value based on country.

Here are two tables, country, and trades
Table [companies]:

```
  +-------------+--------------------+
  |         name|            country |
  +-------------+--------------------+
  |  Alice s.p. |         Wonderland |
  |      Y-zap  |         Wonderland |
  |    Absolute |          Mathlands |
  |  Arcus t.g. |          Mathlands |
  | Lil Mermaid | Underwater Kingdom |
  | None at all |        Nothingland |
  +-------------+--------------------+
```

Table [trades]:

```
trades:
  +----------+-------------+------------+-------+
  |       id |      seller |      buyer | value |
  +----------+-------------+------------+-------+
  | 20121107 | Lil Mermaid | Alice s.p. |    10 |
  | 20123112 |  Arcus t.g. |      Y-zap |    30 |
  | 20120125 |  Alice s.p. | Arcus t.g. |   100 |
  | 20120216 | Lil Mermaid |   Absolute |    30 |
  | 20120217 | Lil Mermaid |   Absolute |    50 |
  +----------+-------------+------------+-------+
```

Expected Output:

```
  +--------------------+--------+--------+
  |             country|  buyer |  seller|
  +--------------------+--------+--------+
  |          Mathlands |    180 |     30 |
  |        Nothingland |      0 |      0 |
  | Underwater Kingdom |      0 |     90 |
  |         Wonderland |     40 |    100 |
  +--------------------+--------+--------+
```

I am trying this: It gives only one value column and it doesn't show the 0 trade country that I want to show also.

```
select country, sum(value), sum(value) 
from
(select a.buyer as export, a.seller as import, value, b.country as country
from trades as a
join companies as b 
on a.seller=b.name)

group by country 
order by country
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join `country` to distinct rows of `trades` which contain only buyer or seller and aggregate conditionally:

```
SELECT c.country,
       SUM(CASE WHEN buyer IS NOT NULL THEN value ELSE 0 END) buyer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN seller IS NOT NULL THEN value ELSE 0 END) seller
FROM country c 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT buyer, null seller, value FROM trades
  UNION ALL
  SELECT null, seller, value FROM trades
) t ON c.name IN (t.buyer, t.seller)
GROUP BY c.country
```

Or, with SUM() window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.country,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.name = t.buyer THEN value ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY c.country) buyer,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.name = t.seller THEN value ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY c.country) seller
FROM country c LEFT JOIN trades t
ON c.name IN (t.buyer, t.seller)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9075f888e373cb0b06ab8d517f68a635).

Answer (score 1):

Try CTE:

```
WITH sold AS (
    SELECT sum(t.value) AS value, c.country FROM trades AS t INNER JOIN companies AS c ON (t.seller = c.name) GROUP BY c.country
), buyed AS (
    SELECT sum(t.value) AS value, c.country FROM trades AS t INNER JOIN companies AS c ON (t.buyer = c.name) GROUP BY c.country
)
SELECT DISTINCT c.country, COALESCE(b.value, 0) AS buyer, COALESCE(s.value, 0) AS seller
FROM companies AS c 
LEFT JOIN sold AS s ON (c.country = s.country)
LEFT JOIN buyed AS b ON (c.country = b.country)
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kgLezmhyiL9BKB2JUsaWYc/0